# Preserving Formulas when exporting to Excel using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, visual-studio-2008, ssis, export-to-excel

I'm currently using a template to generate Excels to export data from my DB to daily reports using SSIS.

This template is a workbook of about 5 worksheets, of which only 1 needs to be filled automatically. This sheet has about 20 columns, of which 2 use Vlookups to auto-populate values based on the value in the preceding column. This is like an ID-Name pair. I need to make ID population part of the export from my DB, while the Name should be populated automatically. This ID-Name relation is maintained in Sheet 2, which I am not touching.

My problem is THIS : The formula is applied to these two columns for about 150 rows (i don't expect more records). So, if my DB returns 120 results, I want my final Excel report from SSIS to have records from A2 to T122. However, what's happening is that once my SSIS package executes, I'm getting an Excel file with the first 150 rows blank... and then my 120 results are filled in. These formula-based Name columns have values "#NA" when the ID column is empty.

How do I tackle this? Would I be able to work around this if I redesigned the Excel formulae to store an empty string instead of #NA when no ID value is present? My end-user needs these formulae to be preserved in his final Excel output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure if you can design a Vlookup that populates empty strings if the reference field is empty, but that's the first suggestion I thought of.

My understanding is that the SSIS engine is probably seeing these #NA values and assuming that these rows already have meaningful data, and thus sidestepping rather than overwriting them. There could be an Overwrite property somewhere, that I haven't found yet.